# alternative of EclipseLink Staticweave Maven Plugin Maven Plugin for java 11?

Tags: java, maven, static, eclipselink, java-11

I need to migrate my project that is using "EclipseLink Staticweave Maven Plugin Maven Plugin" for static weaving to java 11, but this plugin is only compatible with Java 7 + 8.
Is there any alternative of this plugin which is compatible with java 11?

Here the issue I got when compiling :

> MyClass has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime
> (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only
> recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: You should try to use JDK11+ for building ... Apart from that the plugin is simply abandoned (11 years ago) not even maintained for JDK8 or even JDK7... Have you tried to google alternatives?

Comment: https://github.com/empulse-gmbh/eclipselink-static-weave-plugin seems to have jdk8 support, and a few forks move it forward to support EclipseLink 2.7.4, but someone would need to modify (fork) it to use EclipseLink 3.x and jdk 11 in the pom file.

Comment: @aguid I need help. How to resolve this